# How to create spring boot profile for selection in spring boot run configuration

Tags: spring-tool-suite

Does anyone know how you create spring boot profiles to use in a spring boot run configuration? I know I can --spring.profiles.active=dev as launch param, but there is a section in the gui of a spring boot launch config. But I can't seem to get the profiles to populate the drop down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to give a more complete answer than Alex's. Alex is right that you can just type any string there and use it as a profile. (This has the same effect as adding something like `--spring.profiles.active=dev` to the commandline.

The pull-down options come from two sources:

1. history: when you launch the app the current setting for that option is remembered and will be shown to you next time in the pull-down.
2. discovery: the tools will try to 'guess' real profiles you have defined in your project.

Option 2. at the moment is not very smart and the only way it can currently discover that you defined a profile is by looking for `.properties` files that follow the naming convention `application-${profile-name}.properties`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just type the name of you profile in the Combo box located in the Boot launch config tab under right under Main Type and Project combo boxes (it's in the properties editor below). Although the combo box is not populated with options (a bug) you can just type the name of the profile and it would work.

Comment: It's not a 'bug'. The options come from two sources 1. your launch history (i.e. if you used profile once from this UI it is remembered) and 1. from properties files with names like these 'application-${profile-name}.properties'.